# Compilar GCC 12: configure-stage1-gmp: ls -t appears to fail. Check your system clock

Tags: gcc, make

Estoy tratando de compilar GCC 12 con GCC 11.

- gcc (GCC) 11.0.1 20210321 (experimental)

Registro de la consola:

```
/initrd/mnt/dev_save/gcc-12-20210530 make
[ -f stage_final ] || echo stage3 > stage_final
make[1]: se entra en el directorio '/initrd/mnt/dev_save/gcc-12-20210530'
make[2]: se entra en el directorio '/initrd/mnt/dev_save/gcc-12-20210530'
make[3]: se entra en el directorio '/initrd/mnt/dev_save/gcc-12-20210530'
rm -f stage_current
make[3]: se sale del directorio '/initrd/mnt/dev_save/gcc-12-20210530'
make[2]: se sale del directorio '/initrd/mnt/dev_save/gcc-12-20210530'
make[2]: se entra en el directorio '/initrd/mnt/dev_save/gcc-12-20210530'
Configuring stage 1 in host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gmp
configure: loading cache ./config.cache
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... none-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /bin/ginstall -c
checking whether build environment is sane... configure: error: ls -t appears to fail.  Make sure there is not a broken
  alias in your environment
configure: error: newly created file is older than distributed files!
Check your system clock
make[2]: *** [Makefile:5508: configure-stage1-gmp] Error 1
make[2]: se sale del directorio '/initrd/mnt/dev_save/gcc-12-20210530'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:29328: stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: se sale del directorio '/initrd/mnt/dev_save/gcc-12-20210530'
make: *** [Makefile:1008: all] Error 2
```

Se puede ver el error que me sale:

> checking whether build environment is sane... configure: error: ls -t appears to fail.  Make sure there is not a broken alias in your environment
> configure: error: newly created file is older than distributed files!
> Check your system clock

La hora de mi sistema está bien, además, si hago `ls -t` me muestra todo correctamente.

¿De qué manera puedo solucionar esto?

Answer (score 0):

Hay que quitarle los colores al `ls`, y hay que editar el archivo `gmp/configure` al principio.

```
function ls {
    /bin/ls --color=no $@
}
```

Entonces el `configure` queda así:

```
# Copyright (C) 1992-1996, 1998-2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
#
#
# This configure script is free software; the Free Software Foundation
# gives unlimited permission to copy, distribute and modify it.
## -------------------- ##
## M4sh Initialization. ##
## -------------------- ##

function ls {
    /bin/ls --color=no $@
}
```

Luego hacer `make`:

```
tput reset
make
```